# Save NSDate Data when changing views in StoryBoard - iOS

Tags: ios, save, nsdate, uistoryboard, uidatepicker

I have a UILabel that displays a date and A UIDatePicker that can change the date in the UILabel. How do I "save" the date selected when changing the view in a storyboard, so when I go back to the view with the UILabel, the date is selected is still saved as opposed to reverting back to todays date? Here is the code for my UIDatePicker and UILabel that displays NSDate:

```
- (void)flatDatePicker:(FlatDatePicker*)datePicker dateDidChange:(NSDate*)date {

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSCalendar *coptic = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:@"coptic"];
[dateFormatter setCalendar:coptic];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];

if (datePicker.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeDate) {
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM, dd, yyyy"];
} else if (datePicker.datePickerMode == FlatDatePickerModeDate) {
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH:mm:ss"];
} else {
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEEE, MMMM, dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
}
NSString *value = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
self.labelDateSelected.text = value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the NSDate in a variable. Then in viewWillDisappear you save the date:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     [defaults setObject:lastPickedDate forKey:@"lastDate"];
}
```

Then, when you get back to this screen you can verify if there's a date saved and restore it in viewDidLoad or viewDidAppear.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     //another code

     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSDate *date = [defaults objectForKey:@"lastDate"];

     if(date) {
        _datePicker.date = date;
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! I added my code. Could you elaborate further on your answer? I kind of get the general idea but the fact that this is a date is and has been throwing me off.

Comment: Are you already saving or storing that date somewhere before changing to another view/screen?

Comment: No. I don't know how to or where to save the date.

Comment: I edited my answer with a generic solution. You may have some trouble if your app has to store the date for different users this way. Maybe if you can give me more details about this screen or how you app works I may help more...

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much for your patience. I have a NSDate displayed in a UILabel,a UIDatePicker that changes the date, and A button that changes the view to a page that loads a UIWebView. Say the date today is February, 6, 2014, and the user changes it to February 5, 2014, when the user changes the view then goes back, the date says February 6,2014 as opposed to remaining at February 5,2014 as the user had selected previously.

Comment: How are you doing the views change forth and back? Are you using navigation controller, segue/push and pop?

Comment: I am using storyboard "Modal Segue" to change the views

Comment: Please try to update the answer you best you can using my code and my situation and I promise to accept. @GustavoAzOI

Comment: I think that with push segues the controller retain it's state. You really need to save the date for future use or just keep it when the user comes back to the screen?